# Area under the convolution of two functions

Tags: probability

I am a beginner trying to learn probability.

It seems that in probability, if $f$ and $g$ are the density functions of independent RVs, then the area under $(f*g)(t)$ will always be equal to 1! This is good and makes sense to me.

**My question**

I'm wondering if this is just a special case for probability. Let's say the area under $f$ or $g$ is not equal to 1 (so they aren't legit density functions). Is the area under the convolution of $f$ and $g$ equal to say the max of either the area under $f$ or the area under $g$? Or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not the max, it's the product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f * g)(t)\; dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) g(t-s)\; ds\; dt = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\; dt\right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\; dt\right)$$

Comment: Shoot... it's been many years since I did calculus. So the last equality isn't that intuitive for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.